# Characterization of V-stages in the absence of foundation or replacement

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, ordinals, foundations

In the absence of [foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) and [replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement), we can say that $x$ is an [ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) iff $x$ is [hereditarily](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2874529/formal-definition-of-hereditarily/2874533) [well-founded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation) (with respect to the relation $\in$) and hereditarily [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set), where

$$ \text{$a$ is transitive} \longleftrightarrow \forall x \forall y (x \in y \in a \rightarrow x \in a) $$

Is there a similar characterization for stages of the [von Neumann universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe)? That is, $x$ is a stage iff $\phi(x)$ for some first-order formula $\phi$? I suspect the property of being [supertransitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supertransitive_class)

$$ \text{$a$ is supertransitive} \longleftrightarrow \forall x \forall y (x \subseteq y \in a \rightarrow x \in a) $$

might be useful here, but I'm not sure how to prove a definitive characterization. This would allow us to specify (in the absence of foundation and replacement) the stage $V_\alpha$ corresponding to a given ordinal $\alpha$ by saying $V_\alpha$ is the intersection of all $x$ such that $x$ is a stage and $\alpha \subseteq x$.

**Edit:** Let

$$ \text{$a$ is powertransitive} \longleftrightarrow \forall x \forall y (x \in y \in a \rightarrow \mathcal{P} x \in a) $$

If I'm not mistaken, $a$ is supertransitive iff $\mathcal{P} a$ is powertransitive. Can we say that $V_\alpha$ is precisely the intersection of all supertransitive, powertransitive supersets of $\alpha$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naively you'd think that supertransitive is the right definition. Note that supertransitive simply means that $y\in a\to\mathcal P(y)\subseteq a$, which is a good starting point. After all, the $V_\alpha$'s are exactly those transitive sets which compute power sets correctly.

But your intuition is right, it is not enough without Replacement. To see why, A.R.D. Mathias noted that given any limit ordinal $\lambda>\omega$, the class $M_\lambda=\{x\mid\sup(\lambda\cap\operatorname{tcl}(x))<\lambda\}$ is a class model of Zermelo's set theory. But this model only has a von Neumann hierarchy up to $\lambda$ itself. By relative to these models, the traces of the "real" von Neumann hierarchy are supertransitive.

So supertransitive is not enough. You can revert to the actual definition by recursion. First, $\phi(x,\alpha)$ to define that $x=V_\alpha$, and then simply $\exists\alpha\phi(x,\alpha)$. So what is $\phi(x,\alpha)$? The conjunction of the following:

- $\alpha$ is an ordinal, and
- there is a function $f$ with domain $\alpha+1$, such that $f(0)=\varnothing$,  $f(\beta+1)=\mathcal P(f(\beta))$, and if $\beta$ is a limit ordinal, then $f(\beta)=\bigcup\operatorname{rng}f\restriction\beta$. And $x=f(\alpha)$.

But of course, this is not what you want. You want to have some internal property. So instead of this, you need to require that in addition to being well-founded and supertransitive, there are no $\alpha+1$-sequences in $\in$. Namely, for any function $f\colon\alpha+1\to x$, there is some $\beta<\gamma$ such that $f(\beta)\notin f(\gamma)$.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on the last paragraph? What do you mean by an internal property in this context? And why is the last property required?

Comment: An internal property is some property of the set, rather than a property of the set with respect to the universe. So being transitive is, in this sense, internal. Being supertransitive is not *quite* internal, but it's close to that. The last property tells you that the height of your set is at most $\alpha$, so if $\alpha\subseteq x$, and the height of $x$ is at most $\alpha$, then it is $\alpha$. In effect, this is to avoid the situation as in Mathias' weird model, $M_\lambda$.

Comment: I think I see what you mean by internal. "$x$ is transitive" can be expressed as $\forall y_{\in x} \forall z_{\in y} (z \in x)$, i.e. a formula with quantifier variables ranging over already given sets. Supertransitivity, on the other hand, requires $z$ to range over the powerset of $y$. Is this correct?

Comment: With regard to defining $V_\alpha$ in terms of $\alpha$, how about the property of being the intersection of all hereditarily-well-founded supertransitive supersets $x$ of $\alpha$ such that $z \in y \in x \rightarrow \mathcal{P} z \in x$?

Comment: Maybe the condition of being hereditarily well-founded is no longer necessary since it’s implied by the minimality property (bring the intersection of all sets that satisfy the other conditions)?

Comment: Right, sorry. I'm inclined  to say that it's not going to work, but I don't have a counterexample off-hand.